SQL Server equivalent of R Tidy factor() and complete() to fill in missing pairings
I have the follow table, and I want to fill in the missing groupings with 0 in the count column.  I do not know which values are missing from the score column, but know the possible values (eagle, bird, par, bogey, dbogey).  In R/Tidy I can do a factor() and complete() to fill in the missing pairings.  Is there an equivalent way to do this in SQL Server?



player
score
count




P1
par
4


P1
bogey
14


P2
birdie
3


P2
par
14


P2
dbogey
1



Desired Output



player
score
count




P1
eagle
0


P1
birdie
0


P1
par
4


P1
bogey
14


P1
dbogey
0


P2
eagle
0


P2
birdie
3


P2
par
14


P2
bogey
0


P2
dbogey
1




The problem here is your thinking; there is no equivalent because the languages don't work the same way. SQL is a set-based language; it works with sets. When you aggregate in SQL you only get rows for values that exist because those are the only values that exist. As a result you don't get groups for 0 rows because that data to create that group wasn't there. To get rows for values that don't exist you need to first create a data set that has those values, then you can (LEFT) JOIN to your tables.

There are a lot of ways I guess, but usually all solutions means you need to do a sort of cross join of available data and all distinct combinations.
One idea:
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'P1', N'par', 4)
    ,   (N'P1', N'bogey', 14)
    ,   (N'P2', N'birdie', 3)
    ,   (N'P2', N'par', 14)
    ,   (N'P2', N'dbogey', 1)
) t (player,score,count)

SELECT  d.player, x.score, MAX(x.count) AS count
FROM    #data d
CROSS apply (
    SELECT  score, count
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  all_scores.score, 0
    FROM    (
        VALUES  ('eagle'), ('bird'), ('par'), ('bogey'), ('dbogey')
    ) all_scores (score)
    ) x
GROUP BY d.player, x.score

Here, we take the player table and then create a combination of available scores and "all_scores" which has 0 count using a CROSS APPLY.
Then, by aggregating the scores, we take the actual data and compliment it with dummy data for the missing scores.
Final output:



player
score
count




P1
bird
0


P2
bird
0


P2
birdie
3


P1
bogey
14


P2
bogey
0


P1
dbogey
0


P2
dbogey
1


P1
eagle
0


P2
eagle
0


P1
par
4


P2
par
14



